# Gatsby build not compile on save

Tags: javascript, gatsby

Always when I saved .js file in gatsby project in `gatsby develop`, side was rebuild. Now after update from gatsby 3.0 to 4.0 side in same situation does't rebuild. How to fix it ?

```
    System:
    OS: Linux 5.10 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10600K CPU @ 4.10GHz
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.12.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.12.0/bin/node
    npm: 8.1.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.12.0/bin/npm
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^4.0.1 => 4.0.1
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^2.0.0 => 2.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-mdx: ^3.0.0 => 3.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby: 4.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hot reload and dependency tracking are still there in v4. Check if the file you're saving is perhaps not imported into your project?